# What scopes do I need to add in OAuth to search YouTube content by geo location?

Tags: r, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just want to do a simple search of YouTube video content for a keyword by city. I'm currently creating my credentials in the Google Console, but none of the scopes seem the right fit.

I'm assuming I need OAuth, or am I missing a trick with a simplified R script?

Update:

So, following advice, I'm forgetting oAuth. my code is below, but it doesn't work and I'm getting a strange error, "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the official specification of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, you're not required to provide any authorization credentials (as those obtained upon running to successful completion an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow) for invoking this endpoint as you say you want to.

An Google API developer key suffices -- that's to be provided upon request from Google's Developers Console.

That API key is the to be passed on to `Search.list` as the `key` request parameter.

If you still want to use OAuth credentials, then you may choose from the list of [YouTube Data API scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#youtube) the most restrained one: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`.

**Addendum**

So you're using the [`tuber`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuber/tuber.pdf) package.

I looked into [its source code](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber) and learned that (see the function [`tuber_GET`](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber/blob/42a8131098856c8aeb0fcbad70ed5f0e33b9652b/R/tuber.R#L49) that is called by [`yt_search`](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber/blob/42a8131098856c8aeb0fcbad70ed5f0e33b9652b/R/yt_search.R#L153)) that *this library does not allow one to access the API through an API key*. (That because `tuber_GET` calls `yt_check_token`; this [latter function](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber/blob/42a8131098856c8aeb0fcbad70ed5f0e33b9652b/R/tuber.R#L33) generates an error when the Google token is missing.)

As a result of these facts, you are forced to follow the OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow, upon you've configured your Google project (within the Developers Console) to have the scope I mentioned above.

**Addendum #2**

I would recommend you to file a feature request to the maintainer of `tuber`, through this package's [issue tracker site](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber/issues). (I deem the API key use-case to be of good use to a wider user-base of `tuber`.)

If you would like to use something else that'll allow you to employ API keys (thus alleviating OAuth 2 flows), then you could use the *lower level package* [`httr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) (which, by the way, `tuber` is using too).

See [Getting started with httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html). You may find this tutorial quite valuable: [How to Extract Data from YouTube using R and the YouTube API](https://www.yuichiotsuka.com/youtube-data-extract-r/).

Compose an URL with which to invoke `Search.list` through `httr`s `GET` function:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=dishwasher&type=video&location=-33.8688,151.2093&maxResults=50`.

Then, upon calling `Search.list`, proceed processing the JSON response received.

Comment: I see. What do I then need to add to my R Script to access the API with the key?

Comment: @SarahR: Please post your code.

Comment: Added above - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your advice @stvar. Is there an alternative method to using tuber that would mean I can search posts by location without needing OAuth? If there is, I'd appreciate it if you could share an example of the code. Thanks again!